# Has a margin after set overflow:hidden of a div?

Tags: css

```css
.d1 {
  height: 10px;
}

.dd {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dd1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">
  <div class="dd"></div>
  <div class="dd1"></div>
</div>
```

unset the overflow the `dd` and `dd1` is in same line. but if set the two divs not has an equal height.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you are up to. Try to be a little more precise. And one thing I noticed: you don't have the class `dd1` set in your html, but you defined properties for that class in your css

Comment: @BastianSpringer I already edited it.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align), you may read:

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

So what we know as the "baseline" is actually *different* for inline elements that have an overflow that is something other than visible.

To have them to visually appear inline, I believe you'll need to explicitely style the `vertical-align` property:

```
.d1{
    height:10px;
}
.dd{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.dd1{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.d1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.dd {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```